# Pulling and Replacing URL Parameters in Radiant CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, google-ads-api, radiant

I am trying to pull url parameters from AdWords and replace them on the landing page content
using Ruby on Rail Radiant CMS.

For example if the URL from AdWords was: www.example.com/?keyword={keyword}&{copy:matchype}

I want to pull out {keyword} on the landing page that says something like :

"Looking for {keyword}? we can help?"

I think this is possible using something like:

```
<% if params[:keyword] %>
Looking for "<%= params[:utm] %>"? we can help
<% end %>
```

Some help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

```
<% if params[:keyword] %>
Looking for "<%= params[:keyword] %>"? we can help
<% end %>
```

In a nutshell: if the keyword is present as a parameter, then display it with the desired text.

Comment: Do I have to use some sort of get handler?

Comment: this is not php there is not get array wh have the `params`hash here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [if_param_tags extension](https://github.com/jomz/radiant-if_param_tags-extension) for this.
With that in place, you could write:

```
<r:if_param name="keyword">
  Looking for "<r:param name="keyword"/>"? we can help
</r:if_param>
```